# В чем разница между Assert.AreEqual и Assert.Equals C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, юнит-тесты

В чем разница между `Assert.AreEqual` и `Assert.Equals` C#?

Answer (score 8):

[`Assert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aspx) - это обычный класс, который, как и все классы .NET, наследуют от [`System.Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx). [`Assert.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.equals.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) – это просто наследуемый метод [`Object.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx).

[`Asser.AreEquals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243413.aspx) – это метод класса `Assert`, который выкидывает `AssertFailedException` если два объекта не равны. Это штатный способ проверять утверждение о равенстве двух объектов.

---

В версии TestFramework 14.0.0.X `Assert.Equals` перекрыт, и выкидывает исключение, что бы избежать путаницы и не вводить никого в заблуждение. Внутри написано что-то такое:

```
/// Static equals overloads are used for comparing instances of two types for reference
/// equality. This method should <b>not</b> be used for comparison of two instances for
/// equality. This object will <b>always</b> throw with Assert.Fail. Please use
/// Assert.AreEqual and associated overloads in your unit tests.
public new static bool Equals(object objA, object objB)
{
    Asser.Fail("Assert.Equals should not be used for Assertions. Please use Assert.AreEqual & overloads instead.");
}
```